# Multiple Wordpress Loops - second loop is repeating the same post

Tags: wordpress

I've got the following code for two loops on the same page.

My problem is no matter how I filter the posts the second loop doesn't work as expected. The first loop displays the posts correctly the second loop just displays the same post repeating itself.  I have read a few articles on multiple loops, but cannot figure t out.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
$args1 = array(
         'post_type' => array( 'post', 'diary'),
         'meta_key' => 'custom-date',
         'orderby' => 'meta_value',
         'order' => 'asc',
          ); 

$args2 = array( 
         'post_type' => 'bio',
         'order' => 'asc');

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();             
        get_template_part( 'content-1', get_post_format() );
}
wp_reset_postdata();  

$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The 2nd Loop
while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
   $query2->next_post();
       get_template_part( 'content-2', get_post_format() );
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but this may help: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615). Also, research at WPSE as there are many topics covering [multiple loops](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22multiple%20loops%22%20is%3aquestion).

Answer (score 0):

thesecondI got it working changing the loop to this:

```
// Loop 1
$first_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
while($first_query->have_posts()) : $first_query->the_post();
 get_template_part( 'content-1', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

// Loop 2
$second_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
while($second_query->have_posts()) : $second_query->the_post();
 get_template_part( 'content-2', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```